# Ajax.BeginForm() in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

My requirement is show the result in same page with out redirect to another page. i am doing this with Ajax.BeginForm(). but it redirect to another page. can any one help this?

**My js file:**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**My View code:**

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UserAccountInfo", "Account",  new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
 {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div id="result"></div>

<div class="t-12-user">First Name </div>

<div> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "user-input-bx", MaxLength = "50"})</div>

<div class="t-12-user"> Email Address </div>

<div> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailId, new { @class = "user-input-bx", MaxLength = "50" })</div>

<div><input type="submit" value="Save"  /> </div>

    }
```

**controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserAccountInfo(RegisterModel Model)
{
// code
  return Content("Thank you for subscribe", "text/html");
}
```

**web.config:**

```
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

can any one help this, the success message should be show in same page..

Comment: check to add jquery before (ver. 1.8.3, or check new version of unobtrusive ajax and jquery 1.9.2)

Comment: @hVostt: Is any problem with js file. if i remove to give reference it redirecting another page. showing result.

Comment: in AjaxOptions add InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, must works if jquery added before

Comment: remove <div id="result"></div> from form body. id not required, form is self container

Comment: i am not getting. its redirecting to another page. may any problem with js file.

Comment: Now its working. plugin placed in local page. now working. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

return as **json**. I think it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways...

Solution 1: You have to create a partial view inside your /Views/Account folder with your content and return it.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserAccountInfo(RegisterModel Model)
{
// code
return PartialView("_yourPartialView", model);
}
```

Solution2: Just return the same view and use a ViewBag variable to sent any string to the view like this...

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserAccountInfo(RegisterModel Model)
{
// code
ViewBag.VariableName = "Thank you for subscribe";
return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
@ViewBag.VariableName
```